# Create New Sheet and add column header and formula, error finding the new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a new sheet called Data, and adding column names and formulas to get data from other sheets using VBA script. The new sheet gets created, however, on the next step, it is giving the error "Subscript out of range" with the newly created sheet which is already there in the Excel workbook.

please help.

```
Sub CreateDataSheet()
    ' Create a new worksheet called "Data"
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Data"
    
    ' Add column headers in row 3
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
        .Cells(3, 1).Value = "Component"
        .Cells(3, 2).Value = "Component Description"
        .Cells(3, 3).Value = "T18 Document Number"
        .Cells(3, 4).Value = "Module"
        .Cells(3, 5).Value = "Photo Status"
    End With

    ' Add formulas starting from row 4
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        For i = 4 To LastRow
            .Cells(i, 1).Formula = "=Material!G3"
            .Cells(i, 2).Formula = "=Material!H3"
            .Cells(i, 3).Formula = "=Material!J3"
            .Cells(i, 4).Formula = "=Material!M3"
            .Cells(i, 5).Formula = "=IF(C" & i & "=""Not Available"",""Not Available"",""Available"")"
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

No idea why the script is not able to find the "Data" sheet which is just created.

Comment: Try `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = "Data"`.

Comment: You are creating the new sheet in the active workbook (you are not qualifying `Sheets`), but you are expecting it to be created in `ThisWorkbook` (that's the workbook where the VBA code is stored). Maybe a different workbook was active? Or do you want to create the sheet in the active workbook?

Comment: To be on the safe side, replace `ThisWorkbook` by `Workbooks("myfile.xlsx")` (replace myfile with the actual name).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are getting "Subscript out of range". I copy/pasted your code into a blank workbook and it ran fine.

Edit: As FunThomas pointed out, if the workbook with the code is not active when the code is run, it adds the Data sheet to the wrong workbook.

change

```
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Data"
```

to

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Data"
```

Comment: That's not an answer and doesn't help the OP in any way.

Comment: Sure it does. Knowing it's not a problem with the code should lead him to look at other issues with his Excel settings or his computer. It may just need a reboot...

Comment: Only that there *is* a problem with the code, most likely the problem with ActiveWorkbook vs ThisWorkbook. The code runs when ActiveWorkbook = ThisWorkbook, but it fails when ActiveWorkbook v<> ThisWorkbook

Comment: He doesn't use ActiveWorkbook anywhere, he explicitly refers to everything with ThisWorkbook, so the active book/sheet won't matter.

Comment: OP creates the new sheet without qualifying, so it's added to the active worksheet.

Comment: Good catch. If another workbook is active when the script is run, it results in the OPs error.